# Is there any tool to validate the .aspx page nesting & styling structure?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, nested

I am working on a web based application.
I have a .aspx page which includes html, css, javascript & asp.net controls.

The following are cases of nesting elements/ tags:

1. table
2. asp:Panel
3. asp:UpdatePanel
4. div

I have used various combinations of nesting as follows:

```
  1. <asp:Panel>
    <asp:UpdatePanel>
       <table></table>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>
 </asp:Panel>

 2. <table>
    <asp:Panel>
    <asp:UpdatePanel> 
         <table></table>
     <asp:UpdatePanel>
   </asp:Panel>
 </table>

 3. <asp:Panel>
 <asp:UpdatePanel> 
         <table></table>
     <asp:UpdatePanel>
 </asp:Panel>

 4. <table>
   <asp:UpdatePanel>
      <table>
        <asp:Panel></asp:Panel>
     </table>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
 </table>

 5. <table>
   <asp:UpdatePanel>
      <table>
        <div></div>
     </table>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </table>
```

**But when I use such structures, the css style is not applied when page postback occurs.**

**Question:**
Is there any smart way to identify a proper structure. Any tool? Or any kind of unsupportable format,that I have used?
Please help me on this Page structuring issue.
Cause every time manually doing this stuff,is quite annoying.

Edit: Or any information about the page structures, its nesting & behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio Express Version

The designer can you help to validate your structure

Link : http://www.microsoft.com/france/visual-studio/essayez/express.aspx

Comment: http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx -- The version in English... maybe you're french thou?